# value not being copied over

Tags: ios, swift

I have the code:

```
///Get the timeline of the logged in user.
static func GetTimeline(_count: Int) ->  [JSONValue]
{
    var tweets : [JSONValue] = []
    var count = _count

  account.getStatusesHomeTimelineWithCount(_count, sinceID: nil, maxID: nil, trimUser: true, contributorDetails: false, includeEntities: true,
    success: { (statuses) -> Void in
        tweets = statuses!

  }, nil)

    return tweets
}
```

And am trying to copy the value here: `tweets = statuses!`

This method(`GetTimeline`) returns an empty array every time. Through debugging and breakpoints I know that `statuses` contains values, but for some reason this line `tweets = statuses!` is not working so `tweets` remains an empty array.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `getStatusesHomeTimelineWithCount` is non blocking call and `success` callback is executed after `GetTimeline` has already returned empty array.

For non blocking calls you cannot use return value, but you can, for example, use competition handler.

```
static func GetTimeline(_count: Int, competition: (tweets: [JSONValue]) -> ())
{
    var tweets : [JSONValue] = []
    var count = _count

    account.getStatusesHomeTimelineWithCount(_count, sinceID: nil, maxID: nil, trimUser: true, contributorDetails: false, includeEntities: true,
    success: { (statuses) -> Void in
        competition(tweets: statuses!)
    }, nil)
}
```

This is how you possibly work with your current example:

```
let tweets = SomeObject.GetTimeline(10)
// do something with tweets
```

With completion you can do the following:

```
SomeObject.GetTimeline(10, { (tweets) in
    // do something with tweets
})
```

Comment: If i step through it with the debugger, immediately after `tweets = statuses!` tweets is an empty array, so its like its not copying at all, cause that has nothing to do with the return.

Comment: Nvm a `println(tweets)` right after works, not sure why the debugger shows it empty though.

Comment: Are you sure `tweets = statuses!` is ever executed? I guess not.

Comment: But is it executed before return? Try adding print statement before return as well.

Comment: Oh i know it returns before now, thats why i said nvm. Sorry about the confusion. Is there a way to lock the tread until gettimeline is done?

Comment: API is designed to be async and non blocking. The solution with completion closure is common practice. Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: Ok, added an example to answer.